# Connection from Java UI container to couchDB container refuses

Tags: java, docker, connection, port, containers

I have a question regarding Java and couchDB.

My setup:
- a Java UI with an interface to the DB
- a couchDB inside a container, exposed on localhost:5984.

Well.

I have realized a connection between both in my local Windows machine, which worked perfectly.

Now I packed both in containers, but I have a problem:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

What I've did so far:

Docker inspect delivered the following result:

```
  "PortBindings": {
            "5984/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "5984"
                }
            ]
        },
```

And the following:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "860904f9f0d1132bdc3770a3af96627b1675865efe0491a8e51edfba143e8a7f",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "5984/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "5984"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/860904f9f0d1",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "aeff4e87630662516cd35db3d9a26804204420feed65506ff2457f13ddc82b19",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "EndpointID": "aeff4e87630662516cd35db3d9a26804204420feed65506ff2457f13ddc82b19",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am linking my 2 container with:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 5984:5984 --name couchdb klaemo/couchdb
sudo docker run -ti --link couchdb      -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY        -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix java:ui
```

Programmatically, I am connecting in my Java code to localhost:5984 (because my couchDB runs there :P)- but my connection refuses on my container environment.

In which way do I need to modify which statement to realize a working connection between my container? Are there mistakes inside by Bash statements? Or is there a mistake in my programmatic logic because it is binding the container somewhere elsewhere?

Looking forward to your answers.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Inside of a container, my DB is bound to localhost:5984.

But my container is bound on my machine to 172.17.0.1; and my DB is accessable via 172.17.0.2:5984 (external binding).

Thus, I had to use 172.17.0.2 as targeted IP adress.